# How do I switch menus programmatically dependant on which page / category there on?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to switch the menu when the user is on a specific product category.

Ive got the code working on other parts of the site fine but for some reason it doesn't work here :/

`get_queried_object()` returns null

Its currently defaulting to the last menu 'MAIN' as none of the if statements went off but I don't know why.

Im trying to identify the page id or name outside the loop but whatever I try it doesn't work.

See Code:

```
$this_category = get_queried_object();

if(is_product_category('cat1') || $this_category->parent == 125) {
    echo 'cat1';
    $whichmenu = 127;
} elseif(is_product_category('cat2') || $this_category->parent == 86) {
    echo 'cat2';
    $whichmenu = 79;
} elseif (is_product_category('cat3') || $this_category->parent == 85) {
    echo 'cat3';
    $whichmenu = 78;
} elseif (is_product_category('cat4') || $this_category->parent == 90) {
    echo 'cat4';
    $whichmenu = 83;
} elseif (is_product_category('cat5') || $this_category->parent == 89 || has_term('mrl')) {
    echo 'cat5';
    $whichmenu = 82;
} elseif (is_product_category('cat6') || $this_category->parent == 88) {
    echo 'cat6';
    $whichmenu = 81;
} elseif (is_product_category('cat7') || $this_category->parent == 87) {
    echo 'cat7';
    $whichmenu = 80;
} else {
    echo 'MAIN';
    $whichmenu = 77;
}

wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'  => 'primary',
    'container_class' => 'main-menu',
    'menu_id'         => 'primary-menu-mobile',
    'menu'            => $whichmenu,
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id=%1$s class=%2$s>%3$s</ul>',
    'walker'          => new WowmallMainMenuWalker,
) );
```

I use `$this_category->parent` to identify if the child category is a child of a certain parent and if so change the menu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Cheers

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Solved use `wp_get_referer()` to get the url that its referred from.